# how to list integers by 9 in python

Tags: python, list, group-by, iterator, integer

So I'm pretty new here, as in posting a question.  I have gathered some valuable answer for my code using this site.  So here is my question.

I have a list of integers

```
problem = [10, 20, 30, 31, 33, 40]
```

And I would like to have the items to be in individual grouped by 9.

```
desiredResult = [(10, 10), (20, 20), (30, 33), (40, 40)]
```

If you look at the (30, 33).  In my problem variable, I am missing 32.  But, I'm fine with missing 32.  I just want all the 30's listed together.  Or is I has [10, 20, 22, 23, 24, 30], I would like all the 20's listed together.  I'm currently using the following code below.

```
def _ranges(self, i):
        for a, b in itertools.groupby(enumerate(i), lambda (x, y): y - x):
            b = list(b)
            yield b[0][1], b[-1][1]
```

This code works fine except when the listed variables skip a number.  In my above example, this code will return the following.

```
undesiredResult = [(10, 10), (20, 20), (30, 31), (33, 33), (40, 40)]
```

I really don't want the above result.  So can anybody assist me with this problem?

Thanks for reading

Comment: I thought i understood it. but then (10, 10) threw me off. no reward for me :/

Comment: What happened to the 31? Or do you want `[(10, 10), (20, 20), (30, 31, 33), (40, 40)]`?

Comment: what's the desired output?!

Comment: So you want the output to be a list of tuples which are the min and max of each "tens" group listed?  Would input of ```[10, 30, 33]``` produce ```[(10, 10), (30, 33)]``` or ```[(10, 10), (20, 20), (30, 33)]```?

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda is subtracting the value from the index. I'm not sure why you're doing that. Change it to `x//10` (integer division) to get then `10`'s value. ...If that's what you want. It gives the output you're looking for at least, but your question isn't entirely clear:

```
def _ranges(self, i):
        for a, b in itertools.groupby(enumerate(i), lambda (x, y): x//10):
            b = list(b)
            yield b[0][1], b[-1][1]
```

Outputs:

```
[(10, 10), (20, 20), (30, 33), (40, 40)]
```

There's some cleanup to be done of course, but the output is correct

Comment: I think using `//` instead of `/` is better, as it will handle floats as well.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the numbers separated by decade ("I would like all the 20's listed together").

This answer assumes that the input is in sorted order:

```
from itertools import groupby

def bucket_by(lst, divsize, start=0):
    for div,items in groupby(lst, lambda x: (x - start) // divsize):
        yield list(items)

problem  = [10, 20, 30, 31, 33, 40]
minmax = [(min(grp), max(grp)) for grp in bucket_by(problem, 10)]
```

gives

```
[(10, 10), (20, 20), (30, 33), (40, 40)]
```

which *seems* to be what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question now, which is far from clear, this should produce what you are looking for... or very close to it

```
p = [10, 20, 30, 31, 33, 40, 44, 47,59] # can be unordered

groups = [[n for n in p if n/10==i] for i in range(1+max(p)/10) if i]

output = [(min(group), max(group)) for group in groups]
```

**This gives the output:**

```
>>> print output
[(10, 10), (20, 20), (30, 33), (40, 47), (59, 59)]
```

And does *not* need the initial list to be in order

Comment: This is pretty clearly not what OP wants given what he/she has listed for ```desiredResult```

Comment: But you could get it pretty easily with ```[(min(subgroup), max(subgroup)) for subgroup in groups]```

Comment: You can make it return a list of tuples by leaving in the parenthesis